# Family Tree view for family tree web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I am trying to design a family tree for my project. So, i would like to know the best possible way to display the tree structure of the family members in a tree.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this link:

[Looking for a Family Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944146/looking-for-a-family-tree)

It was the first link on Google! One of the answers references this link which has an example of a family tree:

http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html

If that's not what you're looking for, I'm sure you can find a lot of examples on Google.

Answer (score 1):

For family tree, don't use tree structure. Here is some problems with tree structure for family tree :

- Tree only have one root, while family tree must have at least two : husband & wife.
- Using tree structure will be hard to display people's spouse/couple in marriage. Moreso if a person married more than once, and have descendants from each marriages.
- Tree structure can never display marriage between family members/incest.

Have a look at [my sample here](http://scienic-data.com/force-layout-british-monarch-family-tree/) : zoom with mouse scroll, draggable, with interactive tooltip. Created using d3.js

Comment: All good points, but there are many more: all people have just one biological mother and father, the join between two people represents procreation rather than marriage (which is unrelated but often confused with it), the network is a DAG (no loops) but not every ancestor will be unique (see 'pedigree collapse'), people can have children with different partners so not every joined pair has unique people.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free tool at [SVG Family-Tree Generator](https://parallax-viewpoint.blogspot.com/2021/03/svg-family-tree-generator-v60.html) that includes a graphical designer, GEDCOM import, and customisable click operations (e.g. for viewing biographies). The output uses SVGH, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in configurable combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

- pedigreejs (https://ccge-boadicea.github.io/pedigreejs/)
- dTree (https://github.com/ErikGartner/dTree)
- (maybe) Treant.js (https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/)